# PHP PEAR's escape() vs quote() vs mysql_real_escape_string()?

Tags: php, mysql, pear

Been developing an application using PHP's PEAR framework, but ran into an issue where I am double-escaping/quoting input and it wasn't letting newlines (\n) show up properly. Searching forums came up with a mix of answers, but was wondering if anyone has advice for whether using PEAR's escape() or quote() functions is enough for SQL injection security, or should I stick with using mysql_real_escape_string()? I'm trying to use nl2br() + htmlspecialchars() to spit out the content afterwards, and originally incorrectly used the following to escape input:

`$db->quote(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['text'])));`

Comment: You haven't mentioned which package you're using - I'd presume MDB2_MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the escaping function of your database driver. If you're using a PEAR package to connect to the database, use its escaping function. If you're using the raw `mysql` functions, use `mysql_real_escape_string`. Don't use more than one (as you have figured out).

Better yet, go with the times and use modern prepared statements, for example [PHP's PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: +1 for "use prepared statements". For some RDBMSs (e.g. MSSQL) this is the only "well defined" option anyway.

Comment: Ah thanks, for some reason never really got introduced to that. Will check it out!